# Does breastfeeding affect patience, altruism, and risk taking (even as an adult)

Tags: psychology, economics, children

A [2016 paper](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/149799/1/876649274.pdf) from [DIW Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Institute_for_Economic_Research) unambigously states:

> In a sample of preschool
>   children we find that longer breastfeeding duration is associated with higher
>   levels of patience and altruism as well as a lower willingness to take risk.
>   Repeating the analysis on a sample of young adults indicates that the observed
>   pattern is replicable and persists into adulthood. Importantly, in both
>   data sets our findings are robust when controlling for cognitive ability and
>   parental socio-economic status. We can further rule out that the results are
>   purely driven by nutritional effects of breastfeeding. Altogether, our findings
>   strongly suggest that early childhood environment as measured by breastfeeding
>   duration systematically and persistently affects preference formation.

Now given that substantial neurocognitive effects (read: IQ) of breastfeeding have been [touted](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41337/is-breastfeeding-associated-with-a-higher-iq) but [not quite replicated](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29677187), I'm pretty skeptical about the DIW paper ... but this one is perhaps more plausible because it concludes about potentially simpler behaviors, so the outcomes might be mediated (at a biological level) by some hormone(s) or neurotransmitter(s) and/or circuitry in a much more circumscribed area of the brain... and at social level (as hinted at the end of the abstract) breastfeeding could just be a proxy for a more "peaceful" (my term) environment, which could well affect the child's brain development.

Comment: Risk taking (or rather its opposite, risk aversion) has been recently found to have a [brain-structure correlate](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms13822) at least in elders. So there's some potential this might be related... but no data on youth preference (vs. brain structure) yet.